# Where is the line between patentable algorithms and copyrightable creative expression in software?

Tags: copyright, any-jurisdiction

My understanding is that algorithms are protected by patents, and creative expression is protected by copyright.  This could be illustrated by the following hypothetical:

Suppose a company releases a bit of software implementing some novel algorithm, say WinZip with a new better compression method.  This is released under some conventional closed source licence and distributed as compiled object code.

Alice buys a copy of this software, looks at the object code that performs the compression, extracts the algorithm as a mathematical formula and reimplements the algorithm.  She then puts this code in a software product.

Bob buys a copy of this software, puts the object code that performs the compression through a decompiler, takes the resulting few hundred lines of code and puts this code in a software product.

If the company has a patent on the algorithm then both of these software products would infringe upon this patent.  If the company has no patent and is relying on copyright to protect their product, my understanding is that while Bob would infringe, as the decompiled code would include creative expression that was in the original code, Alice would be in the clear as she only takes the mathematical logic.

Now suppose instead of a human, Alice or Bob, we have an machine learning system, perhaps a large language model like [Github Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot) but working from object code rather than text prompts and actually checking the functionality as it goes.  What features would we look at to determine if there is a breach of copyright?  Would it be the output, how similar is it, how many different ways of doing the same thing are there?  Would it be the details of the operation of the machine learning system?  Would it be details of the task being solved, where a simple algorithm would receive less protection than a complex system?

As far as jurisdiction is concerned the question probably would be: Can you do what is described anywhere and distribute the product everywhere?  Assuming this procedure is NOT performed in the USA would probably simplify the issue.

Comment: It isn't an either or analysis. Both forms of protection could be afforded to the same work.

Comment: @ohwilleke The question is premised on the fact that the same work (in this case a software product) can be protected by both forms of IP.  However they protect different aspects of the thing, and this question is about how one is the real world can distinguish between these aspects.

Comment: `Assuming this procedure is NOT performed in the USA would probably simplify the issue.` - why would you think that? "The rest of the world" has, quite obviously, more diversity in how it approaches law than the US, even taking into account the various states.

Comment: @KFK My thinking was the existence of the DMCA.  My understanding is that this would make anything the supplier did to stop you decompiling their code illegal to breach.  As they could say any obfuscation introduced at compile time was such a protection this could be easily criminalised after the fact.  As I understand it this sort of provision is not usual around the world and so excluding it would simplify the issues that would need to be addressed in an answer.

Comment: @User65535 in that case, that’s really three questions instead of one (copyright, patent, retroengineering liability). Possibly four, if one thinks that AI/Copilot etc. are a different question (in my view it’s all one part of the copyright question). Maybe ask separately?

Comment: @KFK I am trying to making it only about copyright.  I was trying to exclude the retroengineering liability by excluding the US where I know it is a specific issue outside of IP law.  I introduce patents as that is the distinction I want to draw.  I am sure such an algorithm would brech a patent, but I think it would not a copyright and the distinction between the two seems the crucial point.